# connect multiple signal to a slot

Tags: qt

I've the follwoing issue.

There are two `signals` :

```
void buttonChanged(int);
void pulseWidthValue(int);
```

`buttonChanged` is emitted from a slot `nextBtn`:

```
void Program::nextBtn()
{
    m_currentBtn++;
    if(m_currentBtn > btnGrp->buttons().size())
    {
        m_currentBtn = 0;
        phaseOver = true;
        saveToXMLFile();
    }

    emit buttonChanged(m_currentBtn);
}
```

it's connected as follows:

```
 connect(ui->btn_nextPhase, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Program::nextBtn);
connect(this, &Program::buttonChanged, this, &Program::paintBtn);
```

the `signal`, `buttonChanged` is used in another slot to paint button:

```
void Program::paintBtn(int id) // how do I change the def of this function to receive to signal?
{



     if(id==1)
     {
         ui->btn1->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn);
         ui->btn2->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn3->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
     }

     else if(id==2)
     {
         ui->btn1->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn2->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn);
         ui->btn3->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
     }

    else if(id==3)
    {
         ui->btn1->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn2->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn3->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn);
    }

    else
    {
         ui->btn1->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn2->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
         ui->btn3->setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
    }


    ui->label_7->setText(QString::number(pw_value)); // this pw_value is from the other signal pulseWidthValue
}
```

the basic idea is , there are 3 phase buttons , clicking `Next` will switch between these buttons and change its color. Now I need to use the other signal `pulseWidthValue` inside `paintBtn`

Now I come to the question:

How do I connect two signals,  `buttonChanged` and `pulseWidthValue`, (both signals are coming from different functions) to the `paintBtn` slot?

Comment: Sorry, but could you provide a better explanation what you try to achieve? What do you mean by connecting two signals - using connect or what?

Comment: @Vasilij , Hi , How to connect two signals, buttonChanged and pulseWidthValue, (both signals are coming from different functions) to the paintBtn slot?, how do I change the definition of slot , inorder to get both the signals?

Comment: you just do it, make two connections, if arguments are compatible should be no problem.

Comment: @PabloYaggi, Hi, could you please give an example?

Comment: Why did you not use switch?

Answer (score 1):

Qt allows you to connect multiple times even to the same slots. It even allows you to connect between signals.
Check this example, is not meant to be functional but descriptive enought to see many options and accesability.

```
class A:public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
...
signals:
    void signalA1();
    void signalA2(const QString &);
}
class B:public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT...
signals:
    void signalB();
public slots:
    void slotB();
}

class C:public QObject
{
...
public:
    C(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
    {
       a=new A(this);
       b=new B(this);
    }
    void connectionTest()
    {
       connect (a,&A::signalA1,b,&B::slotB) ; // one connection to slot B::slotB 
       connect (this,&C::signalC,b,&B::slotB); // another connection to B::slotB
       connect (a,&A::signalA1,this,&C::slotC) ; // another connection from A::signalA, slotC is private so only I can connect
       connect (b,&B::signalB,this,&C::signalC); // connection from signal to signal
       connect (a,&A::signalA2,this,&C::slotC); //connection from A::signalA2 to C::slotC 
                                                //with different argument count, but compatible as slotC doesn't need an argument
       
       connect (a,&A::signalA1,b,&B::slotB) ; // duplicate connection to slot B::slotB  (signalA1 will trigger slotB two times)
    }
signals:
    void signalC();
private slots:
    void slotC();
private:
    class A *a;
    class B *b;
}
```